# How do frameworks (like Spring) configure the Servlet container without web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

<sub>(I already know the answer, but because I often find myself re-looking for the answer, so I post it here as documentation for myself and others. This is [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) on Stackoverflow.)</sub>

## Background intro

Many Servlet developers have read the book "Head First Serlet & JSP" to get their "Certified Web Component Developer Exam" or just to learn Servlets. But the book hasn't been updated since 2009, and only covers Servlet 2.4. A lot has changed since then. The current latest version is 4.0.
One of the things that changed is the boot process of servlet web applications, which can make it unclear what happens during startup and how the web application is initialized.

## Question

In Servlet version 2.4 and lower, web.xml is used to fully configure web applications. But higher version seem to have other ways to configure web applications, without touching web.xml and without annotations. For example, web frameworks provided as .jar files are somehow able to hook into the Servlet container and add url mappings.

How does this mechanism work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Introduction

In Servlet 2.4 (November 2003) a *servlet container* (such as Tomcat and Jetty) simply booted the web application by looking for the file `WEB-INF/web.xml` (the *deployment descriptor*). The file web.xml contains references to servlets, filters and listeners, with their associated url patterns and parameters. Using web.xml the servlet container knows exactly where to find everything and how to configure them.

Since Servlet 3.0 (December 2009), web.xml is optional, you can also use annotations or a programmatic configuration instead.

Annotations are simpler in use. They are located in the [javax.servlet.annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/package-summary.html) package, and allow you to annotate a servlet with @[WebServlet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html), a filter with @[WebFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html), and a listener with @[WebListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html). The servler container will then automatically find and detect these classes. Annotations however do provide less configuration features than web.xml and a programmatic configuration.

This text further focuses at how programmatic configuration can be configured and how it starts Spring MVC. It's a bit more complex than annotations, but does give you and framework designers more control over the booting process.

If you wanted to use a web framework before Servlet version 3.0, you have to add a servlet or filter to your web.xml and configure the framework from there. After this initialization, you could start writing classes (usually non-Servlet classes) known by the web framework to create a web application.

Since Servlet 3.0, the system is modular. This allows framework and library designers to initialize the servlet container without you having to configure the framework via web.xml. You can immediately start writing the web framework specific classes to create a web application without touching Servlet classes.
(It's also possible in Servlet 3.0 to create your own web.xml and still let the framework do the initialization of the framework, without it being defined in web.xml.)

### How can a framework or library hook into the Servlet container automatically?

When booting up, the Servlet container first looks for the deployment descriptor located at `WEB-INF/web.xml`. If this file has a `metadata-complete` attribute set to false, or if it isn't defined at all, the container will also search for annotated classes, such as @WebServlet.

Apart from looking for web.xml and annotated classes, since Servlet 3.0, the container will also look for `META-INF/web-fragment.xml` files within the .jar files located in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

The file web-fragment.xml is a *web fragment*, which is
(quote from [Java Servlet Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr369/index.html))

> a logical partitioning of the web application in such a way that the
> frameworks being used within the web application can define all the
> artifacts without asking developers to edit or add information in the
> web.xml. It can include almost all the same elements that the web.xml
> descriptor uses. However the top level element for the descriptor MUST
> be web-fragment and the corresponding descriptor file MUST be called
> web-fragment.xml. The ordering related elements also differ between
> the web-fragment.xml and web.xml

The content of web-fragment.xml is like web.xml, but with a `web-fragment` root element instead of `web-app` element:

```xml
<web-fragment xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-fragment_3_0.xsd"
              version="3.0">
  <filter>
    <filter-name>FrameworkFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>framework.FrameworkFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FrameworkFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-fragment>
```

The exact ordering of loading of a single web.xml and multiple web-fragment.xml files, can be configured using the `<absolute-ordering>` and `<ordering>`.

Apart from web fragments, there is also a programmatic method to partition the web application: by writing an implementation of the interface  [`javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html?is-external=true). ServletContainerInitializer gives access to the [`ServletContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html), which contains methods to programmatically add servlets, filters and listeners.
To use `ServletContainerInitializer`, it has to be specified in a file located in `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`. The content of this file has to be the fully qualified path to the implementation class.

## How does this work for Spring MVC?

Although Spring MVC does contain a [`web-fragment.xml`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.1.x/spring-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/web-fragment.xml), it doesn't define any servlets, filters or listeners. Spring uses the [`META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.1.x/spring-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer) file to refer to its own ServletContainerInitializer implementation class, which is the class [`SpringServletContainerInitializer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.1.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.java).

SpringServletContainerInitializer is a ServletContainerInitializer, so it receives a ServletContext on startup. The goal of SpringServletContainerInitializer is to pass the servletContext to a more developer friendly [`WebApplicationInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html), so that you can add servlets, such as Springs [`DispatcherServlet`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html), which is a front-controller that directs incoming requests to other controllers. (See [spring-framework-reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-servlet) about how to configure a DispatcherServlet to Spring.)

Spring MVC doesn't provide a concrete implementation of WebApplicationInitializer, only a number of abstract classes, so that you have control over the booting process. In case of Spring Boot, a concrete implementation is provided: [`SpringApplicationWebApplicationInitializer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.1.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-cli/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/cli/app/SpringApplicationWebApplicationInitializer.java) to reduce the amount of boilerplate code.

## Further info

A detailed description about how the Servlet container booting process exactly works, can be found in the official [Java Servlet Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr369/index.html). Further info about Spring MVC can be found in the [Spring Framework reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html).